# For what value of n this relation holds $\frac{x}{\pi}+\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos(n\pi)\sin(\pi x)=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I want the value of $n$ for which this relation must satisfy:
$$
\frac{x}{\pi}+\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos(n\pi)\sin(\pi x)=0
$$ How to solve this?

Comment: please use back slashes for pi, cos, sin, etc. `\sin(\pi x)` = $\sin(\pi x)$. Compare to $sin(pix)$ without the backslashes.

Comment: As it stands it makes little sense to ask "for which $n$". Do you mean to ask where to start and stop the summation?

Comment: @amWhy: I believe the summation is with respect to $n$.

Comment: I think the Question must be for what value of $x$ the series expansion holds.

Comment: Yes, I agree. The op had clearly indicated using underscore, $n\geq 1$. I suspect the OP is trying to find the range of summation for $n$, perhaps?

Comment: Actually I am new to this site. I am learning how to post a question. Thanks for support.

Comment: The original post (title) had $\frac x{\pi} + $`\underscore{n\geq 1}`$\sum\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos(n\pi)\sin(\pi x)=0$

Comment: @user3563283 After all these edition and roll back, the question still didn't make any sense. Please restate what you really want to ask. If you don't know how to type the correct formula, just state it in words, we can fix the formula for you.

Comment: I framed the equation asif it is in LaTex. I want the range of $n$.

Comment: @user3563283: That doesn't make any sense! Your expression depends only on $x$, and $n$ is just a dummy summation variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{2}{n\pi}\cos(n\pi)=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\frac{2}{\pi}\ln 2
$$ Hence, your equation is
$$
\frac{x}{\pi}-\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\pi x)\ln 2=0
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x-2\ln 2\:\sin(\pi x)=0
$$
Setting $u=\pi x$, you get
$$
\sin u=\alpha \:u
$$ which admits a transcendental solution $u:=u ( \alpha )$ with $
\alpha=\dfrac{1}{2\pi\ln 2}$.